# Send and then receive file in the same socket? [Java]

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client server configuration that needs to do the following:

1. Client sends video to server.
2. Server receives video and converts it.
3. Server sends converted video to client.
4. Client receives converted video.

I know how to transfer a file and convert it, so the first two steps are done. But then I need to send the video back. The naive approach, which would make the server look like this:

```
//Receive file
File copy = new File("copypath");
byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000000];
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copy);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
int currentTot = bytesRead;
do {
    bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentTot,
            (bytearray.length - currentTot));
    if (bytesRead >= 0)
        currentTot += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead > -1);
bos.write(bytearray, 0, currentTot);

//Convert file
File converted = convert(copy);

//Send file back:
bytearray = new byte[(int) converted.length()];
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(converted);
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
bin.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);   
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
```

Client code would be:

```
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
//System.out.println("Sending file...");
os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
os.flush();

//  System.out.println("File transfer complete");

//Y recibe
File copy = new File(convertedName);
bytearray = new byte[10000000];
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copy);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
int currentTot = bytesRead;
do{
bytesRead =
is.read(bytearray,currentTot,(bytearray.length-currentTot));
if(bytesRead >= 0)currentTot+=bytesRead;
} while(bytesRead > -1);
bos.write(bytearray,0,currentTot);
```

... is not working. Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "... is not working." ?

Comment: By not working I mean that the process isn't completed. Both client and server just stay there. What's curious is that not even the initial transfer is completed. (But if I comment out the code for steps 3 and 4 it works fine).

Comment: And can we have some of the client code ?

Comment: Try using a system call tracer (`strace` on Linux, for example) to see at which point the communication stops in your code.